# How to use class which defined below?

Tags: c++, class

```
class A{
 public:
 B b;
};

class B{
 public:
 A a;
};
```

I can't write in A class "B b" because class B defined below. Is any way to make it work?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible. You need to use a pointer or a reference in one of the classes.

```
class B; // forward declare class B
class A {
public:
  B * b;
};

class B {
public:
  A a;
};
```

As to why it isn't possible: A contains a B contains an A contains a B ... There's no end to the recursion.

If you're used to languages (such as e.g. java) where all object variables are pointers/references by default, note that this is not the case in c++. When you write `class A { public: B b; };` a complete `B` is *embedded* into A, it is not *referred to* within A. In C++ you need to explicitly indicate that you want a reference (`B & b;`) or a pointer (`B * b;`)

Comment: +1 for being the only one who mentioned pointers *and* references.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it: Inside an object of class B there's an object of class A, and inside it there's an object of class B. This is physically impossible! What will be the size of object B?

```
sizeof(B) > sizeof(A) > sizeof(B)
```

You must use pointers, like the other answer suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make it work. You should use forward declaration and a pointer to one of the class

```
class B;
class A{
 public:
 B *b;
};

class B{
 public:
 A a;
};
```

That is because when you're writing `B b` the compiler must know what B is. But if you make a forward declaration then compiler will know that `B` is some class and you will be able to create pointers and references of B.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you change at least one of the two member objects to a pointer. You would be able to declare a member pointer to such an object by forward-declaring the other class, like this:

```
class B;

class A{
 public:
 B* pb;
};

class B{
 public:
 A a;
};
```

**The reason for this:**

The compiler needs to know how objects of each class (`A` and `B`) will be laid out in memory. This includes *how much memory* will be needed for each object. Since class members require an amount of memory that depends on *their* members, it follows that the compiler can only allow you to declare a class member if it has seen the declaration of that member's class *first*.

Pointers, on the other hand, always take up the same amount of memory. This is why it's enough for you to tell the compiler "`B` is a class; I want a pointer to `B` here". The "`B` is a class" part corresponds to the `class B;` line above, which is called a *forward declaration*.