# How to declare two inter-linked classes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245774/how-to-use-class-wich-defined-below), but in delphi.

```
type
  TThreadPopulator = class(TThread)
  private
    _owner:TASyncPopulator; //Undeclared identifier
  end;

type
  TAsyncPopulator = class
  private
    _updater: TThreadPopulator;
  end;
```

Solution of mentioned question is not applicable to delphi

Comment: The pertinent documentation is here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Classes_and_Objects#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [`Forward Declarations and Mutually Dependent Classes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Classes_and_Objects#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes) documentation.

```
type (* start type section - one unified section "to rule them all" *)

  TAsyncPopulator = class; (* forward declaration, it basically serves just to
  fix SizeOf(TAsyncPopulator) so compiler would be able to draft dependent types'
  in-memory layout. Down the CPU level `class` and `pointer` is the same, so now 
  Delphi knows SizeOf(TAsyncPopulator) = SizeOf(pointer) to compose further types *)

  TThreadPopulator = class(TThread)
  private
    _owner:TASyncPopulator;
  end;
    
  TAsyncPopulator = class (* the final declaration now, it should go WITHIN 
  that very TYPE-section where the forward declaration was made! *)
  private
    _updater: TThreadPopulator;
  end;

  ....

type 
(* now, that you had BOTH forward and final declarations for TAsyncPopulator 
   spelled out above, you finally may start another TYPE-section, if you choose so. 
   But only after them both, and never should a new `type` section be inserted 
   in between those declarations. *)
  ....
```

Use the source, Luke! Your Delphi installation has full VCL and RTL sources for you to read and watch and learn. And it uses this template a lot. Every time when you ask yourself "how I could do it", just think along "how did Borland do it" and pretty chance that you can already get a ready-made example in Delphi-provided sources.

Comment: It gives error [DCC Error] Populator.pas(12): E2086 Type 'TAsyncPopulator' is not yet completely defined. I am using delphi XE2

Comment: do u literally use this code without leftovers from your own ? That is the pattern you can use in almost every VCL unit like Controls, Forms, etc.

Comment: This code DOES compile in XE2 Update 4 Hotfix 1. You code is somehow different - check it attentively. Most probably you close one TYPE-section and initiate another TYPE-section way too early. Forward-declarations and final ones can not go in separate sections. I think you just mixed your old code with one of mine.

Comment: @Arioch, no, your code couldn't compile at the time OP posted the comment. You've added the forward class declaration after that comment (but in 5 minutes editing period).

Comment: @TLama - no, of all my edits - i did not changed the code. I changed comments, i fixed typo - but the very code i entered right after i saw the question and i did not changed that. More so, when i posted my answer and saw another one - i immediately pointed at TYPE issue there too. The code did not changed, only the comments and surrounding text did.

Comment: @TLama - what do you talk about at all ? 5 minute is only about comments, i can edit the answer even 5 years after!!! where is that code of mine that "did not compile" ? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13005810/revisions

Comment: @Arioch, I know, what I've seen (and OP's comment is just a prove of it). When you post the answer, you have 5 minutes to edit the post without adding that change to a revision history. You just added that forward declaration after OP's comment about compiler error. Howgh! :-)

Comment: @TLama: No. Believe or not - i did not. The code was not changed a  bit. And my 1st comment suggest that TS did not used MY code, but rather his own made under influence of mine. *But thanks for the 5 minutes hint. Is it cumulative ? can i make continuous editing like each 4 minutes ?*

Comment: @Arioch'The No, 5 minute grace period starts when you first post answer. That's it. For the first 5 minutes after posting, all edits are not recorded in revision history.

Comment: Rather than "Use the source", this answer would be improved with an explanation of how forward declarations work, and an explicit demonstration of what is meant in the docmentation by "A forward declaration must be resolved by a defining declaration of the same class within the same type declaration section."

Comment: @David - For now i consider it self-descripting. If in future would be questions, maybe would consider re-making it. Or you may edit if you wish. As of now this answer to me seems laconic and enough.

Answer (score 3):

Use this before any class definition. Forward class works in Delphi 2010. I don't know witch version of delphi you have but it's the only solution I can think off.

```
type   
 TAsyncPopulator = Class;
```

Hope I helped

Comment: I tried. But it gives error [DCC Error] Populator.pas(10): E2086 Type 'TASyncPopulator' is not yet completely defined. I am using Delphi XE2

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan it should work on your delphi version so check the syntax you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: @Niyoko - because you ended TYPE section too early. Forward declarations work in the single section span. Read Delphi manual regarding type declaration. PS. Also - there is "retag" link above. It is generally proper think to put the tag for your exact delphi version additionally to generic `delphi` tag

Answer (score 2):

Besides using a forward declaration, you can also create a subclass to solve this:

```
TThreadPopulator = class(TThread)
  type 
    TAsyncPopulator = class 
      _updater: TThreadPopulator;  
    end;

  var 
    owner: TAsyncPopulator;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing that always trips me up is that the forward classes need to be in the same type block (which can be easy to miss in complex units).

i.e. this works:

```
type
   TClassB = class;
   TClassA = class
     PropB: TClassB;
   end;
   TClassB = class
     PropA: TClassA;
   end;
```

This fails:

```
type
   TClassB = class;   // E2086 Type 'TClassB' is not yet completely defined.
   TClassA = class
     PropB: TClassB;
   end;

type
   TClassB = class
     PropA: TClassA;
   end;
```